# scale on bar plot in reverse direction - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code below is from [Creating a horizontal bar plots in the reverse direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341962/creating-a-horizontal-bar-plots-in-the-reverse-direction).

I'd like to make a horizontal bar chart in the reverse direction but with a **fixed scale**. I'd like the scale of the plot to be fixed to **0 to 50** rather than the current 0 to 30.

I've tried changing `scale_y_continuous()` to `scale_y_discret()` and I've tried adding  `ylim()` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks!

```
mtcars
mtcars$`car name` <- rownames(mtcars) 


ggplot (mtcars, aes (x=`car name`, y=-mpg)) +         
  geom_bar (position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity",fill="red",colour="black") + 
  coord_flip () +  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", position = "top") +    
  scale_y_continuous(name = "mpg",
                     breaks = seq(0, -30, by = -10),  
                     labels = seq(0,  30, by =  10))  + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: just add `limits = c(-50,0)` to the `scale_y_continuous`function? So `scale_y_continuous(name = "mpg",limits = c(-50,0),
                     breaks = seq(0, -50, by = -10),  
                     labels = seq(0,  50, by =  10))` or simply run `scale_y_continuous(name = "mpg",limits = c(-50,0))`. In addition use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar`

Comment: Use `range =c(0, 50)` for y-axis.

Comment: @Jimbou You could define the y-axis before plotting. Like: `y <- list(
  showgrid=TRUE,
  title = "Title here",
  titlefont = f,
  range=c(0, 50)
)`. Then use it under `theme()`. It a long route I get it. But easy if you want to make quick changes later. What do you think?

Comment: @SamAct How you use it under `theme()`?

Comment: @Jimbou if i remember correctly its `axis()` command inside `theme()`

Comment: @SamAct which one? Please show the complete code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use [limits](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/continuous_scale) to set a limit on your y scale, It's a numeric vector of length two describing the scale limits.

as @jimbou mentioned in the comments, your code will be something like this:

```
ggplot (mtcars, aes (x=`car name`, y=-mpg)) +         
  geom_bar (position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity",fill="red",colour="black") + 
  coord_flip () +  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", position = "top") +    
  scale_y_continuous(name = "mpg",
                     limits = c(-50,0),
                     breaks = seq(0, -50, by = -10),  
                     labels = seq(0,  50, by =  10))  + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

you can also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)